# Creating Array of deck of cards [Java]

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to start a program that will create an array with all possible values of a deck of cards. Not entirely sure they best way to go about this but my rational here was that I would create a static array with the suits and the card values. Then I created a changeable array so that I could add the two array values like this `deck.add(suit[suitNumber] + value[valueNumber]);`. I used a for loop to automate the process.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class arrayTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] suit = {"D, H, S, C"};
    String[] value = {"A, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, J, Q, K"};
    int suitNumber = 0;
    int valueNumber = 0;
    ArrayList<String> deck = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (suitNumber = 0; suitNumber == suit.length; suitNumber++) {
        if (suitNumber == 3) {
            suitNumber = 0;
        }
        if (valueNumber == 13) {
            valueNumber = 0;
        }
        deck.add(suit[suitNumber] + value[valueNumber]);

    }
    System.out.print(deck);
}

}
```

When I run the program at this stage, I get no output other than "[]" in the console. Also the debug section shows that the deck array has 10 values of "null". Sorry I am new to programming. Anyone see what I have done wrong?

Comment: `suitNumber == suit.length;` evaluates to false so loop wont run

Comment: In addition to this, your `String` arrays each consist of only one `String`, which I doubt is what you intend. You need to enclose each `String` within its own set of quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Card` class that has two properties:

1. Suit
2. Value

Then you can use the ArrayList to hold `Card` object:

```
//ArrayList<String> deck = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
```

You would also need a double loop to load each Card into the ArrayList:

```
for (int suitNumber = 0; suitNumber < suit.length; suitNumber++)
{
    for (int valueNumber = 0; valueNumber < value.length; valueNumber++
    {
            deck.add(new Card(suit[suitNumber], value[valueNumber]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for (suitNumber = 0; suitNumber == suit.length; suitNumber++)

What are you trying here ?

suitNumber == suit.length; i.e 0==4 which is always false and you loop does not execute.

Answer (score 1):

```
  String[] suit = "H,D,C,S".split(",");
  String[] vals = "A,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,J,Q,K".split(",");

  List<String> deck = new ArrayList<String>();
  for(String s:suit)
     for(String v:vals)
        deck.add(s + v);
  System.out.println(deck);
```

Of course do what you want with the data. Create a card class or something.

Answer (score 0):

here:

```
 for (suitNumber = 0; suitNumber == suit.length; suitNumber++)
```

should be

```
for (suitNumber = 0; suitNumber <= suit.length; suitNumber++)
```

and you forget to increment valueNumber

it's not a good way to do this, I should do something like:

```
 for (valueNumber= 0; valueNumber<= value.length; valueNumber++){
    for (suitNumber = 0; suitNumber <= suit.length; suitNumber++){
       deck.add(suit[suitNumber] + value[valueNumber]);
    }
 }
```